# WSO2 APIM clustering - how to improve the response time?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, gateway, api-manager

I clustered APIM with 1 manger gateway node and 2 or more work node to test APIM response time.
   it did not give me good data.
   without APIM,my api response time is 20 ms.though APIM 400ms-1s.
   how to confige this question?

Comment: I hope you didn't disable gateway cache which is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to slove my problem,i find all bolgs.

finally ,[in this blog](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.jp/2015/03/how-to-fine-tune-api-manager-180-to-get.html),Sanjeewa Malalgoda give a solution.

Then,after my test,the result is effiective.

Answer (score 1):

There are several handlers in APIM, through which all API calls are going. Eg. Authentication, Throttling, CORS etc.

You can [enable analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics) in APIM and see a latency breakdown graph among stages. See `Figure 9` of [this article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/09/article-generating-insights-with-wso2-api-manager-analytics/). Then you can identify if there are any handlers which cause a large latency. Then we can decide how to fix that.

Comment: thank you for your relply. i did not use analytic. 

My purpose is to optimize gateway or fine turn APIM.